# Accessing entity object then saving it

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am attempting to get and then update/add the changes that I made to the EmailSetting record.

Here is my code:

```
  public partial class EmailSetting
  {
    private Entities entities;

    public IEnumerable<EmailSetting> GetEmailSettings()
    {
      try
      {
        if (entities == null)
        {
          entities = Entities.DefaultConnection();
        }
        return from x in entities.EmailSettings select x;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        MiscClasses.Logging.Log(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, "An error occurred attempting to GetEmailSettings.", ex);
        throw;
      }
    }

    public EmailSetting GetDefaultEmailSetting()
    {
      try
      {
        if (entities == null)
        {
          entities = Entities.DefaultConnection();
        }
        return (from x in entities.AppSettings select x.EmailSetting).FirstOrDefault();       
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        MiscClasses.Logging.Log(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, "An error occurred attempting to GetDefaultEmailSetting.", ex);
        throw;
      }
    }

    public void SaveDefaultEmailSetting(EmailSetting emailSetting)
    {
      try
      {
          entities.SaveChanges();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        MiscClasses.Logging.Log(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, "An error occurred attempting to GetDefaultEmailSetting.", ex);
        throw;
      }
    }

  }
```

The problem is that if I add a record, it's not saving at the SaveDefaultEmailSetting, it's not doing anything when I have a new record. How do I check if the record is added vs updated when saving then save it according to it's status?

Comment: Where's the code where it's failing to add?

Comment: @JosieG.Bigler I have updated the question, does that answer your question?

Comment: I don't see where you are adding `EmailSetting` to the `Entities`.  Somewhere you should do `entities.Emailsetting.Add(emailSettingObject);` and then you'll call `entities.SaveChanges();`

Comment: what happens if it is an update and not an add?

Comment: Then you would call `entities.Emailsetting.Update(emailSettingObject);` and then `entities.SaveChanges();`

Comment: how do I distinguish between the two? How do I know if it is an update or an add?

Answer (score 0):

To lay out an example, if you want to add these methods to your `EmailSetting` class these should complete your Update and Create transactions.

```cs
    public void AddEmailSetting(EmailSetting emailSetting)
    {
      try
      {
          entities.EmailSetting.Add(emailSetting);
          entities.SaveChanges();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        MiscClasses.Logging.Log(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, "An error occurred attempting to GetDefaultEmailSetting.", ex);
        throw;
      }
    }

    public void UpdateEmailSetting(EmailSetting emailSetting)
    {
      try
      {
          entities.EmailSetting.Update(emailSetting);
          entities.SaveChanges();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        MiscClasses.Logging.Log(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, "An error occurred attempting to GetDefaultEmailSetting.", ex);
        throw;
      }
    }
```

Also, injecting the entity into the object that it tracks seems weird?  Maybe that's a pattern I'm not familiar with.

The way I would have gone about it would be to either have a separate class that manages the entities, or just inject the dbContext and perform the CRUD operations on the entity I needed from the context.

For example, lets say you had a controller (and the dbContext was injected into your Controller) that received the object you wanted to Add (follow the same pattern for update) you would do the following;

```cs
[Route("~/add")]
public IActionResult Add(EmailSetting emailSetting)
{
    // Whatever null checks or validation you wanted to do here.
    _dbContext.EmailSetting.Add(emailSetting);
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();     

   //return or redirect to whatever view/method after adding.
}
```

You would follow the same pattern for Update, changing the route and the method name, and then for the `_dbContext.EmailSetting.Update(object);`.